# Set sound for android application

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm developing an application in android. I have added Media Player sound for my application mainpage with `OnPause()` and `OnResume()`,but the problem is when I go to another page the sound stops. Is there any code can make it continue? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Play the sound in your service.Not the activity.